# Работа jQuery после ресайза окна

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

У меня есть скриптик isotope, который делает плавное перемещение элементов на экране.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#isotope').isotope({
        itemSelector : '.h_item',
        layoutMode : 'fitRows',
        containerStyle: {position: 'relative', height: '1000px'}
    });
});
</script>
```

Проблема в том, что вначале все криво, но как только мы изменеим хоть на пиксель размера окна (по горизонтали или верикали), то все становится на свои места. Так вот пришла идея сделать, так, что бы тот код выше начинал работать только после первого ресайза окна. Как такое сделать?
P.S. может кто работал с этим плагином и знает в чем проблема без танцев с бубном?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не очень хорошее решение, конечно, но попробуйте программно вызвать "ресайз" окна:

```
$(window).resize()
```

Comment: да, я уже этим воспользовался, все работает прекрасно. Спасибо